# Jw player not working in mobile web browsers (android & IOS devices)

Tags: android, ios, android-webview, jwplayer, wowza

JWPlayer which is integrated in web browser(website) is working fine on all desktop browser where as coming to mobile it is not working and also showing that "Error loading media: File could not be played" can any one help me in fixation of this,Here I am attaching concern code thanks in advance.

```
    <html lang="en"> 


     <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>  
         <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, handheld" href="style.css" />
                <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js" ></script> 
                <script>jwplayer.key="UqsxqSzE4fs4e3/+JJ4g2zVO2jxpFkwT31IzfQ=="</script> 
</head>   
<body>
                <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
                <div id="player"></div>
                <input type="text" id="stream" value="rtmp://192.168.2.108:1935/live/test.stream"></input> 
                <button id="start">Start</button>
                <button id="stop">Stop</button>
                <div id="status"></div>  
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: This is RTMP only. You can't use RTMP on mobile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTMP is, by definition, a Flash format. There's no Flash on a mobile device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply if I am using flash fox browser in my mobile it is working fine and also can you say how can i over come this issue thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide two sources in the JW Player setup - the first source RTMP, then an MP4 source for the mobiles. With a premium or enterprise license for JW Player, you could use HLS as the fallback, but that won't fly on an Android device. Streaming in Android is still a mess.

Comment: BTW, I'd be curious to see a link to your live page. The way you have that set up, it's not clear to me that JW Player is being invoked at all. There's no setup() block for the player.